# Cancel the sleep function?

Tags: vb.net, vb6

If I'm using a code to sleep for 60 seconds and decide I want to cancel it out how do I stop it?

It seems the few times I have used sleep it has to complete before me to stop it.

A code sample in vb.net or vb6 would be fine I can work with either language.

EDIT:

What I was doing was just making a temp file deleter that sits in the system tray and deletes the temp files after so much time. Allowing the user to set the interval to whatever they wanted it to be. If they want it to be 24 hours, then set it to 24 hours then execute the code.

I know i'm not the only person that has ever tried to do this. Seems weird that you guys don't understand what I am doing.

The problem is the only way to cancel the action from being done if they want to stop it is to close the entire application out.

Comment: You cannot “cancel” a `Sleep`. If you told us why you think you need `Sleep` we could suggest an alternative.

Comment: +1 because the question doesn't deserve the downvotes.

Comment: You never "use a code" you can only "use *some* code."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Store the start time in a variable
- Add the sleep time to it
- Use a Timer control to check wether the sleep time has passed

An example project in VB6:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 checkbox control: name=Check1  style=1 - Graphical
'  1 textbox control: name=Text1
'  1 timer control: name=Timer1
Option Explicit

Private mdatEnd As Double

Private Sub Check1_Click()
  Dim dblSleep As Double
  If Check1.Value = vbChecked Then
    dblSleep = Val(Text1.Text)
    mdatEnd = DateAdd("s", dblSleep, Now) 'add sleeptime (in seconds) to the current time
    Timer1.Interval = 1000                'check time every 1000 miliseconds (every second)
    Timer1.Enabled = True
  Else
    StopCheck
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
  Dim lngDiff As Long
  lngDiff = DateDiff("s", Now, mdatEnd)   'calculate remaining sleep time
  Caption = CStr(lngDiff)                 'show remaining sleep time
  If lngDiff <= 0 Then                    'show when sleep has finished
    MsgBox "sleep finished", vbOKOnly, "Sleep"
    StopCheck
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub StopCheck()
  Timer1.Enabled = False                'stop checking time
End Sub
```

The sleep time in the textbox is the number of seconds to sleep.
If you want to specify it in minutes, then you have to change the DateAdd to minutes as well, and you can change the DateDiff and the timer interval to minutes as well ... the same for any other period-resolution

Instead of a timer control you can also use a thread or simple loop, but be sure to make it not too tight

Answer (score 2):

Once you invoke `sleep`, you have no way out.  You cannot force it to stop.

The best way I have come up with is to `sleep` for 10 seconds at a time, and check if you want to continue every time the 10 second interval happens.

After `6` such `10 second` sleep cycles, go on your merry way.

Comment: +1 but 10 seconds is very long. I would suggest sleep for 0.1 or 0.01 seconds instead. "Checking whether you want to continue" is presumably very fast.

Comment: The smaller your sleep interval, then more error you will add to the total wait time.

Comment: True. If accuracy is important you could calculate the end date-time in advance and then loop until the current date-time is after that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'cancel' the sleep.  It suspends the thread for the specified amount of time and doesn't return until the time is expired.

As the MSFT .NET docs indicate:
*The thread will not be scheduled for execution by the operating system for the amount of time specified.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is there some other way to do it other then sleep or timer? Sometimes I need to pause a code for 30 minutes or even an hour. Last time I tried a timer it said I couldn't do anything more then 60 seconds for the interval.

Comment: @FrostByte - If this is in the main UI thread, you shouldn't be locking it up for 30 minutes at a time.  If it is in another thread, there are other ways to prevent code from executing for a specified period of time.

Comment: If you need to pause for 30 minutes or an hour, you're much better off architecturally changing to an event driven workflow, where the next step can only be taken if the event happens (file lands in folder, for example)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class instead.  You can schedule an event to fire at some interval (to the nearest millisecond; I have no idea where you got the "60 second" interval from).  You would handle that event and do what you need to do.  If you want to "cancel" before the interval occurs, then just turn off the timer or restart it.  This all takes place outside of the UI thread, so you don't tie up the UI in the meantime.  If you are trying to do something with the UI in your `Elapsed` event then you will need to use `Invoke` to access the UI elements.

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but you are almost definitely in need of a `Timer` rather than `Sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

Weird behavior for an application (to be sent to sleep for 30 min or 1 hour...)

Anyway, you asked, I suggest, but I already know my answer will be as weird as the question if not even more.. so, it's not really an answer, just one another suggestion or so (and I hope there will be more) Without knowing what the sleep is required for, not sure the following could help.

---

Use two global boolean variables :

```
    Private isSleeping As Boolean = False ' or Protected or even Public...
    Private cancelSleeping As Boolean = False
```

Then use a `Timer` (also a global variable). The Timer.Tick is handled by a method that uses some logic to store how long the `isSleeping` variable has been set to True. This could be achieved by using either :

1. an iterator : `Private sleepStep As Integer = 0`. If you set the `Timer.Interval` to one second (1000) then increment sleepStep by 1 each time the Tick Event is handled. For one hour or sleeping Mode, sleepStep would reach 3600 with a timer interval of 60000...
2. a `StopWatch` (better IMHO, System.Diagnostics) : `Private sleepSpan As StopWatch`. You'll read the `sleepSpan.Elapsed` (TimeSpan) in the Tick event handler.

So you must find a way to :

- Initialize the Timer Interval like `Public Sub SleepMe(ByVal Duration As Integer)`. If you want a very precise way to break the sleep mode, you'll have to set a very small value for Interval, but the Timer.Tick is by nature very imprecise. If you use the iterator, beware of stackoverflowing (if your application sleeps too long)
- Handle the sleep cancellation in the Timer.Tick (`Timer.Enabled = False`) : Cancel when the entire sleep duration is elapsed. Cancel when a sleep cancellation is invoked : by reading the value of cancelSleeping.

---

```
Private Sub HandleTimerTick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim TimeElapsed As Boolean

    If cancelSleeping Then
        myTimer.Enabled = False
        isSleeping = False
        cancelSleeping = False
    Else
        ' ...
        ' Find here if the sleeping duration has elapsed
        ' ...
        If TimeElapsed Then
            myTimer.Enabled = False
            isSleeping = False
            cancelSleeping = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Then the sleep method :

```
Public Sub SleepMe(ByVal NewDuration As Integer)
    ' For iterator :
    ' compute some duration control if required
    ' ...
    sleepStep = 0
    ' or for timespan :
    sleepSpan = New StopWatch()

    ' ... what else ?
    ' oh ! yes : initialize the Timer.Interval !
    ' how long ? It depends on you.. :/
    mySleepTimer.Interval = XXX

    ' ...

    ' Toggle sleep mode On.
    isSleeping = True
    cancelSleeping = False ' not really required here, 
    ' depending on how you update cancelSleeping in other part of the code..
    mySleepTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Then for almost anything that has to be put on hold while your application is sleeping, you'll have to check the value of `isSleeping`... X_X

This approach is generally too restrictive and too complicated to be usefull enough. Sometimes, it helps to put all those in a custom class with members like :

- Public Sub mySleepClass.SleepMe(XXXX)
- Public Sub mySleepClass.CancelSleep()
- Public ReadOnly Property mySleepClass.IsSleeping() As Boolean
- ...

and use those members to control how the application should behave. That looks really like a backgroundworker (that does nothing than wasting time) isn't it...

Don't forget to dispose of everything that should..

I used this in a traffic game (roads, cars, trains, planes...) I've made long ago, until I sank in the complexity of the code. I ended implementing their own sleepModes for each object instead of controlling the whole in the core of the application. But I'm still unhappy with the approach, if someone has a better suggestion, perhaps, I'll try to recode that game..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Thread.Sleep, you can use `await Task.Delay(duration, cancellationToken)`.